# How to evenly size font with CSS

Tags: css

I would like to make each font take equal amount of space, similar to fonts displayed in a Linux terminal

**For example:**

[image]

Notice that each character take same amount of space

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a font designed so that every character in it is of the same width.

These are called [monospaced fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monospaced_typefaces).

The CSS generic [font family](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family) `monospace` will select the system's default font of that style.

Various values of the [`white-space` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) such as `pre` will cause multiple spaces to be treated as significant, although the `<pre>` element should be used if the semantics of the text mean that the spacing is significant rather than just presentational.

Comment: Thanks for the mention about white-space property.

Answer (score 2):

It's not super clear to me what you're asking for, but I'll try to help.

-Terminal fonts generally used monospacing, here is a list of monospaced fonts: https://www.typewolf.com/top-10-monospaced-fonts

-If you're looking to evenly increase the amount of spacing between letters I suggest checking out letter spacing for css: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_letter-spacing.asp